# How to pass NSSize and NSRect to PyObjC KVC convenience accessor

Tags: cocoa, pyobjc, key-value-coding

I'm writing some AppKit code in PyObjC on Lion, and I want to use the special KVC accessor style, e.g. `obj._.field = value` instead of `obj.setField_(value)`.

I have success setting NSString- and NSDictionary-valued properties with KVC, but I'm having trouble with wrapped Objective-C structs, specifically NSSize and NSRect.

When I try to set a KVC property of type NSSize or NSRect, the Objective-C layer throws an NSInvalidArgumentException.  Cocoa is trying to invoke `sizeValue` or `rectValue` on the Python object.

Here is a log at the interactive prompt that shows the issue:

```
% python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from AppKit import *
>>> NSApplication.sharedApplication()
<NSApplication: 0x7fcf6ae071f0>
>>> w = NSWindow.alloc().init()
>>> w._.minSize = NSSize(100, 200)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_convenience.py", line 141, in __setattr__
    return self.__object.setValue_forKey_(value, key)
ValueError: NSInvalidArgumentException - Class OC_PythonObject: no such selector: sizeValue
>>> r = NSMakeRect(100, 200, 300, 400)
>>> w._.frame=r
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_convenience.py", line 141, in __setattr__
    return self.__object.setValue_forKey_(value, key)
ValueError: NSInvalidArgumentException - Class OC_PythonObject: no such selector: rectValue
```

PyObjC seems to be wrapping the structs in a OC_PythonObject proxy, which doesn't implement the expected KVC converter.  The KVC code assumes that the value is like an NSValue and implements the struct accessor methods.

Is there a way to set struct-valued KVC properties in PyObjC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple. Even in plain ObjC, the structs would need to be wrapped in an [`NSValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/) before being passed through KVC. You can do the same in Python:

```
>>> w._.minSize = NSValue.valueWithSize_(NSSize(100,200))
>>> w.minSize()
<NSSize width=100.0 height=200.0>
>>> w._.frame = NSValue.valueWithRect_(NSMakeRect(100, 200, 300, 400))
>>> w.frame()
<NSRect origin=<NSPoint x=100.0 y=200.0> size=<NSSize width=300.0 height=400.0>>
```

See ["Wrapping and Unwrapping Structs"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-SW2) in the KVC Programming Guide for more info. Also, don't forget when doing this that not all classes are KVC compliant for all attributes.

Comment: @Jay: It's not a workaround. That's the way Cocoa (specifically KVC) works, in both Obj-C and PyObjC

Comment: You are correct that KVC works that way, and having read the PyObjC release notes, I can even accept that making NSSize objects incompatible with NSValue is by design.  Yet the extra code one has to write is still a workaround for a lack of information passing between PyObjC and the Objective-C runtime.  PyObjC passes the Python NSSize object to the Objective-C runtime as an opaque OC_PythonObject, the same way it passes non-Cocoa Python objects.  If that class implemented sizeValue, or if the _ proxy created the NSValue wrapper, then the user code would be significantly clearer.